# Accessing a large singleton object in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

I have a very large singleton object which contains a 2500 X 80000 double array. When I try to access it in a multithreaded environment, as the number of thread increases, the time to access the object increases. If there a way I could keep the access time of the object same irrespective of the number of threads.

I am just reading the array. There is no changes being made in the array. There is no synchronization in the code

Comment: Are you synchronizing access to the object?

Comment: Are you synchronizing the access to the array elements?

Comment: How are you synchronizing the array?

Comment: Are you reading or writing?

Comment: What are you calling "accessing" here? Is that a simple element access?

Comment: I am just reading the array. There is no changes being made in the array. There is no synchronization in the code.

Comment: How is this array stored? In memory or in a file? If in a file, have you tried and mapped it into memory instead? (well, that may not even be needed, a `RandomAccessFile` and relying on OS caching would be enough)

Comment: I have stored it in memory. It seems when I try to access this array, since multiple threads are accessing the same memory space so it is slowing down the performance.....will it not be the case with RandonAccessFile handler?

Comment: Sounds like a cache problem.

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause of the problem is ineffective caching. Caching depends on a thread getting back to a line before there is enough other cache activity to push the line out of the cache. As the number of threads increases the probability of a thread reusing a line goes down.

If at all possible, access the array in its natural order, second index changing fastest. That reuses lines as soon as possible and reduces the amount of cache space each thread needs to run well.

A possible solution to try is to use e.g. a semaphore to limit the number of threads reading the array simultaneously to the number that gives the highest throughput. That may be greater than one, but will not be unlimited.

Another solution is to increase the number of processors, and therefore the cache space, in proportion to the number of threads.

A third option is to revisit using so many threads. It may be more efficient to have a finite thread pool, and a queue of tasks for them to work on.

Comment: Thanks Patricia, I will try and use them.

Comment: Also, if you have a small memory, or a lot of space in use, the 1.5 GB that the array occupies may be an issue. The solutions are the same, except substitute increasing memory for increasing processors. The main memory can be regarded as a cache with a large size and line size.

Comment: Is there a way in which I could split that array or store in a better data structure so as to avaoid this problem

Comment: The array is already split - it is really a length 2500 array of references, each of which points to a length 80000 array of double. What are you actually doing with the array? Why do all these threads need to access it?

Comment: Patricia....i have stored this array to do some calculations... based on the input data, datapoints will be needed from this array in a multi-client environment and there will be many concurrent requests which will be accessing it. I am currently testing it. If I keep the number of threads to 2 or 3 then the performance is better. But if I increase the threads to 50 or 60 then performance suddenly degrades.

Comment: Have you considered using a ThreadPoolExecutor? That way, you can decouple the number of concurrent requests in the system from the number of threads executing them. If your application runs on different systems you may want to consider adjusting the number of threads according to the system size, such as number of processors.

Comment: It seems that it will run the best with a single thread only as even if the number of threads processing it is increases to 5, the performance goes down. Seems, the problem is the object which of 1G size

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing is reading, then you have the most efficient solution software wise.  What is more likely to be a problem is you are exhausting a resource, e.g. you have more threads than CPUs or you have more data than can fit in your caches efficiently.

For example, if you have one thread, it has full access to you L3 cache, e.g. 12 MB.  If you have two threads each cpu can use half the cache if there is no overlap.  If you have 24 threads then each CPU has only 0.5 MB and it has to share a highly contended resource.

In tests I have done, you can max out the bandwidth of the L3 cache with just 2-3 threads depending on what you are doing.

BTW: You should get better caching efficiency if you either.

- buy a CPU with a larger L3 cache and a wider memory bandwidth, you can get up to 24 MB for 2011 pin Xeon processors.
- use float or int instead of double.  I have used short with two fixed decimal places for some use cases.

> I am just reading the array. There is no changes being made in the array. There is no synchronization in the code

At one place I have seen each critical thread ran on its own machine.  This would guarantee constant performance for you.  I suspect however, you need to consider options which will make the most of your hardware and realise your hardware has limitations (like your budget ;)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to my problem. Instead of storing the data in two dimensional array, I stored the data in a single dimension array and the results are much much faster then storing the same in two dimensional array. Apparently, java doesn't handle double dimensional arrays as efficiently as single dimensional arrays.